# how to sort items inside a combobox?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7, delphi-xe8

I have a combobox that I add some numbers to, like in the following code

```
combobox1.Items.BeginUpdate;
try
  combobox1.Sorted := True;
  combobox1.Items.Add('0');
  combobox1.Items.Add('2');
  combobox1.Items.Add('1');
  combobox1.Items.Add('3');
  combobox1.Items.Add('5');
  combobox1.Items.Add('4');
finally
  combobox1.Items.EndUpdate;
end;
```

I want to sort these numbers as 0,1,2,3,4,5... and so on, inside the `combobox`.

I enabled the Sorted property but items did not sort.

How could I possibly sort items with numbers inside the `combobox` ?

I load items in `combobox` from TList with this code:

```
var
  J : integer;
  themes : Tthemes;
begin
  ComboBox1.Items.BeginUpdate;
  try
    ComboBox1.Sorted := True;
    for J := 0 to listitems.Count - 1 do
    begin
      themes := listitems.Items[J];
      ComboBox1.Items.Add(themes.designid);
    end;
  finally
    ComboBox1.Items.EndUpdate;
  end;

  ComboBox1.ItemIndex := 0;
```

Comment: I tried your code and the result is sorted! XE7 and assuming Vcl project.

Comment: weird i do the same code and the result comes the same as they added without sorted iam using this code in dll project

Comment: I can't imagine how the project being a dll could have any effect. But just in case, try with a new vcl forms project. Drop the combobox and a button on the form. In the buttons OnClick event copy - paste the code above. No other design time settings.

Comment: i tested it in single exe file its sorting normally . maybe because the record i load is from tlist ? is this will make difference ? more code added

Comment: You are aware that if you have strings with numbers like `'1','2','3','10','14','24','35','37'`, they will be sorted on the first digit first: `'1','10','14','2','24','3','35','37'`, right?

Comment: ComboBox items are sorted alphabetically only, not numerically. If you need the latter, copy the items to a separate `TStringList`, sort it with its `CustomSort()` method (converting strings to integers during sorting), then copy it back to the ComboBox.

Comment: i will work around this @RemyLebeau

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
  combobox1.Sorted := False;
  combobox1.Items.Add('0');
  combobox1.Items.Add('2');
  combobox1.Items.Add('1');
  combobox1.Items.Add('3');
  combobox1.Items.Add('5');
  combobox1.Items.Add('4');
  combobox1.Sorted := True;
```

Comment: Are Sorted procedure keeps the original ItemIndexes, or new one are assigned? I have an app which uses ItemIndex property and it seems like they are reordered.